# Pagination not worked in sorting

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, sorting, pagination

I have a problem. I am working on user can input his information like, name, image, etc. Then all user information will show on page with categories and sorting also with pagination.

Problem 1. Sorting and category worked well individually, but sorting not works in after select category. I want when user select a category then he can also able sorting by selected category.

Problem 2. My pagination code worked, but not properly because when I select category it's not worked categorized, same problem with when select sorting.

Thanks!

**This is for category:**

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <select name="theme_category_name" >
        <option class="form-control" >Select Your Categories</option>
        <?php 

        global $wpdb;
        $table_name ="theme_category";
        $category = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * from $table_name" );
        foreach($category as $categories){
            ?>
            <option class="form-control" ><?php echo $categories->theme_category_name;?></option>
            <?php
        }
        ?>

    </select> 
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="category_submit" value="GO"/>
</form>
```

**This if for sorting:**

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="Newest" value="Newest ">
   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="high_price" value="High Price">
   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="low_price" value="Low Price">
</form>
```

**all php code:**

```
<?php
        global $wpdb;
        $table_name ="theme_upload";
            //Pegination
            $pagenum = isset( $_GET['pagenum'] ) ? absint( $_GET['pagenum'] ) : 1;      
            $limit = 2; // number of rows in page
            $offset = ( $pagenum - 1 ) * $limit;
            $total = $wpdb->get_var( "select count(*) as total from $table_name" );
            $num_of_pages = ceil( $total / $limit );
            $rowcount = $wpdb->num_rows;

        $category_s = $_POST['theme_category_name'];
        //Category Select
        if(isset($_POST['category_submit']))
        {
            $result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * from $table_name WHERE theme_cat_name = '$category_s' limit  $offset, $limit");
        }
        //Newest
        elseif(isset($_POST['Newest']))
        {
            $result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * from $table_name ORDER BY id DESC limit  $offset, $limit");
        }
        //Sorting for High Price
        elseif (isset ($_POST['high_price'])) 
            {
                $result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * from $table_name ORDER BY theme_price DESC limit  $offset, $limit");
            }
        //Sorting for low Price
        elseif (isset ($_POST['low_price'])) 
            {
                $result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * from $table_name ORDER BY theme_price ASC limit  $offset, $limit");
            }
        // Default Order
        else {
                $result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * from $table_name limit  $offset, $limit" );
        }


        if($rowcount>0){    
            foreach($result as $results){
                //var_dump($results);

            ?>

            <?php

            }
        }
        else{
            echo "<tr><td cols=an='5'>No records found</td></tr>";
        } 
            ?>


<?php
//Pagination Strat  //
$page_links = paginate_links( array(
    'base' => add_query_arg( 'pagenum', '%#%' ),
    'format' => '',
    'prev_text' => __( '&laquo;', 'text-domain' ),
    'next_text' => __( '&raquo;', 'text-domain' ),
    'total' => $num_of_pages,
    'current' => $pagenum
) );

if ( $page_links ) {
    echo '<div class="tablenav" style="width: 99%;"><div class="tablenav-pages" style="margin: 1em 0">' . $page_links . '</div></div>';
}
//Pagination END //

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that your scripts are running SQL queries in isolation of each other.

I have proposed some modifications to your code to build 1 query based on the available form data.

Also you should be escaping your inputs or doing some sort of checking incoming $_POST values, definitely not just passing the $_POST value of your category name into an SQL query. I have added a suggested solution for ensuring the $_POST value is valid by loading up the categories first and checking there is a match.

You can read more about using prepared statements with the wordpress database class here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks

**For your HTML section:**

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <select name="theme_category_name" >
        <option class="form-control" value="all" >Select Your Categories</option>
            <?php 

            global $wpdb;
            $table_name ="theme_category";
            $category = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * from $table_name" );
            foreach($category as $categories){
                ?>
                <option class="form-control" value="<?=$categories->theme_category_name?>" ><?php echo $categories->theme_category_name;?></option>
                <?php
            }
            ?>

        </select> 
        <!-- Change these to buttons, share the name=submit -->
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="submit" value="category_submit">GO</button>

        <!-- Move these into the same form tag and make them buttons -->
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="submit" value="Newest">Newest</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="submit" value="high_price">High Price</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="submit" value="low_price">Low Price</button>

</form>
```

**For your php section:**

```
<?php
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name ="theme_upload";
        //Pegination
        $pagenum = isset( $_GET['pagenum'] ) ? absint( $_GET['pagenum'] ) : 1;      
        $limit = 2; // number of rows in page
        $offset = ( $pagenum - 1 ) * $limit;
        $total = $wpdb->get_var( "select count(*) as total from $table_name" );
        $num_of_pages = ceil( $total / $limit );
        $rowcount = $wpdb->num_rows;

    $category_s = $_POST['theme_category_name'];

    // Get a list of valid categories
    $categories = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT theme_category_name from theme_category", ARRAY_A );

    // Sort them into an array of values
    $allowed_categories = array_column($categories, 'theme_category_name');

    // Add in the default value (defined on your page)
    $allowed_categories[] = 'all';

    // Check the incoming value is valid / allowed
    if(in_array($category_s, $allowed_categories) === false) {
        // Set up your own error handling here
        echo "Invalid category";
        exit;
    }

    // define defaults
    $where = $order_by = "";

    // If a category is specified, define the WHERE clause
    if($category_s !== 'all') {
        $where = " WHERE theme_cat_name = '$category_s' ";
    }

    // Toggle your order_by values
    switch($_POST['submit']) {
        case 'Newest':
            $order_by = " ORDER BY id DESC ";
            break;

        case 'high_price':
            $order_by = " ORDER BY theme_price DESC ";
            break;

        case 'low_price':
            $order_by = " ORDER BY theme_price ASC ";
            break;
    }

    // Run only 1 SQL query to process all of the incoming information
    $result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * from $table_name $where $order_by LIMIT $offset, $limit" );

    if($rowcount>0){    
        foreach($result as $results){
            //var_dump($results);

        ?>

        <?php

        }
    }
    else{
        echo "<tr><td cols=an='5'>No records found</td></tr>";
    } 
        ?>


<?php
//Pagination Strat  //
$page_links = paginate_links( array(
    'base' => add_query_arg( 'pagenum', '%#%' ),
    'format' => '',
    'prev_text' => __( '&laquo;', 'text-domain' ),
    'next_text' => __( '&raquo;', 'text-domain' ),
    'total' => $num_of_pages,
    'current' => $pagenum
) );

if ( $page_links ) {
    echo '<div class="tablenav" style="width: 99%;"><div class="tablenav-pages" style="margin: 1em 0">' . $page_links . '</div></div>';
}
//Pagination END //
?>
```